# Flat bands in metals

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, orbitals

When I look at the angular momentum resolved band structure of the sodium (Na), there are two flat band at very low energies (p at around -25 eV and s at around -50 eV). What should I understand from these flat bands. Are they flat just because there are not any bands close to them?

Answer (score 1):

These bands correspond to atomic core states of sodium. They have no band width because these electrons cannot move through the lattice.

Comment: The band width is small because the Na $2s$ and $2p$ state on neighbouring atoms have negligible overlap. But the calculations usually treat them in the same way as the other electrons.

Comment: Therefore, could  we say that their bands are flat because they don't overlap with their adjacent orbitals?

Comment: Yes, but it is the hamiltonian matrix element that determines the bandwidth rather than the overlap. It is true that the more the unperturbed atomic orbitals overlap the larger this matrix element is.